# Iteration Scheme Converging

Tags: numerical-methods

I am in a class called Numerical Analysis and I have a quick question regarding iterative schemes. How would I go about finding out whether or not a certain iteration scheme converges to a unique solution?

Say the iteration scheme is something like:

$$\vec{x_{k+1}} =   [A]\cdot \vec {v_k}   +   \vec c$$

where $\vec {x_{k+1}}$ is the $2$x$1$ matrix $\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}x \\ y\end{matrix}\right\rbrace$ corresponding to the $k+1$ iteration, $\vec{v_k}$ is the $2$x$1$ matrix, say,$\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}\cos x+\sin y \\ \cos x - \sin y\end{matrix}\right\rbrace$ corresponding to the $k$th iteration, $[A]$ is a $2$x$2$ matrix of integers and $\vec c$ is a $2$x$1$ matrix of integers.

I don't want you to do the work for me, just need help determining what method to use! Thank you!

Comment: No, v(k) is a vector where (just as an example) v1(k) = cos(x(k)) + sin(y(k)) and v2(k) = cos(x(k)) - sin(y(k))

Comment: Given a starting vector x(0)

Comment: You might prove that the mapping $\vec x_k \to \vec x_{k+1}$ is a contraction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a basic method, called [gradient descent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MethodofSteepestDescent.html). It works by using the derivatives of the function, nominally:
$$\vec x_{k+1}=\vec x_k - \epsilon f'(\vec x_k)$$
Where $\epsilon$ is a certain (small) positive step size. The derivative of the function in question is taken using partial derivatives, so that you are stepping each independent variable in the appropriate direction to minimize it. If you want to maximize the function, just make $\epsilon$ a small negative number.

Comment: How will that allow me to prove that it converges?

Comment: Because the relative error will approach zero:
$$rel_{error}=\frac{|x_{k+1}-x_k|}{x_k}$$